# In Max-Heapify algorithm, what's the purpose of verifying that left and right elements are smaller than the heap-size?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, max-heap

Here is the psuedocode of the Max-Heapify algorithm :

```
MAX-HEAPIFY(A, i)
1. l <- Left(i)
2. r <- Right(i)
3. if l <= heap-size[A] and A[l] > A[i]
4.   largest <- l
5. else largest <- i

[...]
```

What's the purpose to verify that the index of the left heap is smaller equal than the size of heap A given in input ?

Comment: Because you are setting index in that if, if it goes beyond size or less than 0 (i.e. overflow or underflow condition) then you would end up getting exception

Comment: You wouldn't want to access elements which are not a part of heap (aka `Out of bounds`).

Comment: You also should make sure that `i` doesn't exceed the heap size.

Answer (score 3):

Here `l` (left) and `r` (right) are the index values of the left and right child, not the values itself, so to make sure the indexes (l & r) don't exceed the size of heap(Heap stored as an array) we check it against the heap size.